# Split a vector into almost equal groups without leftovers

Tags: r, vector, split

I have a vector

```
x<- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

And I want to split it into 5 groups, which will be more or less equal: three groups will contain two numbers and two groups will contain three numbers. In other words, there will be no leftovers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `cut` to define groups and `split` them into separate list.

```
n <- 5
split(x, cut(seq_along(x), breaks = n, labels = FALSE))

#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`2`
#[1] 4 5

#$`3`
#[1] 6 7

#$`4`
#[1] 8 9

#$`5`
#[1] 10 11 12
```

Comment: thank you. How would the solution change, if  ```x``` was a list of names instead? For example ```x<-c("dd", "ff", "rr", "hah", "kek", "ft", "uh", "qw", "er", "gh", "mk", "kk") ```

Comment: Maybe `cut(seq_along(x), ...)` is more general to any situations.

Comment: Yes, `seq_along` is more general. Updated the answer @Julia

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
n <- 5
split(x, sort(x%%n))
split(y, sort(1:length(y)%%n))
```

Data:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
y <- c("dd", "ff", "rr", "hah", "kek", "ft", "uh", "qw", "er", "gh", "mk", "kk")
```